# Performance difference in stream from List v.s Set

Tags: java, java-stream

Will it be any significant performance between these two `anyMatch` in the below streams?

- one created from `List`
- second created from `Set`?

```
        List<Integer> list = List.of(1, 2, 3, 4);
        Set<Integer> set = Set.of(1, 2, 3, 4);

        var result1 = list.stream().anyMatch(i -> (i % 2 == 0));
        var result2 = set.stream().anyMatch(i -> (i % 2 == 0));
```

I tried to measure it, but the result of 1M executions has a difference of around 30milis so it could be a measurement error.

Comment: No, there will be no significant performance difference.

Comment: You will get a difference when creating a Set and putting elements into it, due to its *no duplicates nature*, but once it is created, I dont think anyMatch() will have any differences between list/set..

This 30millis you are seeing might just be other factors, rather than the method itself.

Comment: Where have you got the over time? in `addding values` or `consuming streams`? I think on streans there  is no difference but adding can be because 'Set` needs check duplicated items

Comment: If the `Set` implementation is a `HashSet`, then checking for duplicates won't be expensive, I believe.

Comment: You should *profile* your benchmark. It will probably show you the `.stream()` operation is by far the most expensive. Put in a *lot* more data and try again :)

Comment: @Dilermando Lima, SusanMustafa sets created via `Set.of(…)` are immutable and their factory method throws an exception when there are duplicates. So there’s no “adding values” here.

Comment: In both cases you are simply streaming the items.  So I would expect that they would both perform similarly (since the hashing of the set items provides no advantage here).

Comment: @Holger They are immutable yes, but during creation Set.of(), if you look deeper into the code, you will see it uses setN method, which in turn calls probe() method which verifies if element exists or not.

              int idx = probe(e); 

The meaning was that a Set by nature does not allow duplicates, therefore there must be a check somewhere to verify that :)

Comment: The question *Will it be any significant performance between these two anyMatch in the below streams?* had nothing to do with the initialization of the data structures.

Comment: @SusanMustafa but that’s not relevant to this question.

Answer (score 3):

There is no significant difference. I just benchmarked it with [jmh](https://github.com/openjdk/jmh) (OpenJDK 17):

```
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
public class SetListBenchmark {

    private List<Integer> list;
    private Set<Integer> set;

    @Setup
    public void setUp() {
        list = List.copyOf(generateIntList());
        set = Set.copyOf(generateIntList());
    }

    private List<Integer> generateIntList() {
        var list =  IntStream.range(1, 1_000_000)
                .filter(i -> i % 2 != 0)
                .boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        list.add(4);
        return list;
    }

    @Benchmark
    public boolean measureList() {
        return list.stream().anyMatch(i -> i % 2 == 0);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public boolean measureSet() {
        return set.stream().anyMatch(i -> i % 2 == 0);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Benchmark                     Mode  Cnt  Score    Error  Units
SetListBenchmark.measureList  avgt    5  0.001 ±  0.001   s/op
SetListBenchmark.measureSet   avgt    5  0.001 ±  0.001   s/op
```

Comment: You are benchmarking the classes `LinkedHashSet` and the result of `Collectors.toList()`, typically an `ArrayList`, but not the classes use by `List.of(…)` nor `Set.of(…)` of the OP’s question.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, I just updated my answer to use Set/List.copyof (List/Set.of is called internally). Keep in mind the implementations of Set/List.of are not really defined and could theoretically be different in different JDK implementations.

Comment: Correct. Every benchmark is a snapshot of a particular environment. Even when you use specific implementation classes, their internals can change. But note that your error is too high; it’s the same magnitude as the score. Perhaps, inserting something like `.peek(Blackhole::consume)` into the stream chain ensures that the optimizer isn’t too aggressive.

Answer (score 2):

Just did another benchmark to compare `ArrayList`, `LinkedList`, `ListN`, `HastSet`, `LinkedHashSet`, `SetN`. Each collection is constructed using a List with 1M odd number and adding 4 and then shuffled using fixed seed.

```
Benchmark                              Mode  Cnt   Score    Error  Units
SetListBenchmark.measureArrayList      avgt  200   0.007 ±  0.001   s/op
SetListBenchmark.measureLinkedList     avgt  200   0.016 ±  0.001   s/op
SetListBenchmark.measureListN          avgt  200   0.005 ±  0.001   s/op
SetListBenchmark.measureHashSet        avgt  200  ≈ 10⁻⁷            s/op
SetListBenchmark.measureLinkedHashSet  avgt  200   0.011 ±  0.001   s/op
SetListBenchmark.measureSetN           avgt  200   0.003 ±  0.001   s/op
```

The number of iteration needed to get the even number(4)

```
Collection    No. of iteration
ArrayList     662453
LinkedList    662453
ListN         662453
HashSet       3
LinkedHashSet 662453
SetN          Not fixed*
```

<sub>[* Reason for not fixed](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/739769c8fc4b496f08a92225a12d07414537b6c0/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ImmutableCollections.java#L951)</sub>

Since [`anyMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch(java.util.function.Predicate)) is short circuit operation, the performance really depends on how many iteration is needed to find the first match. As both `ListN` and `SetN` are backed by array, even though `SetN` iteration order is non-deterministic, both should have similar performance on average.

```java
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.*;
import org.openjdk.jmh.infra.Blackhole;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
public class SetListBenchmark {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        org.openjdk.jmh.Main.main(args);
    }

    private List<Integer> listN;
    private List<Integer> arrayList;
    private List<Integer> linkedList;
    private Set<Integer> setN;
    private Set<Integer> hashSet;
    private Set<Integer> linkedHashSet;

    @Setup
    public void setUp() {
        arrayList = getIntStream().collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
        linkedList = getIntStream().collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new));
        listN = List.copyOf(getIntStream().collect(Collectors.toList()));
        hashSet = getIntStream().collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
        linkedHashSet = getIntStream().collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));
        setN = Set.copyOf(getIntStream().collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }


    private Stream<Integer> getIntStream() {
        List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) {
            ints.add((2 * i) + 1);
        }
        ints.add(4);
        Collections.shuffle(ints, new Random(0));
        return ints.stream();
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void measureArrayList(Blackhole blackhole) {
        blackhole.consume(arrayList.stream().anyMatch(i -> i % 2 == 0));
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void measureLinkedList(Blackhole blackhole) {
        blackhole.consume(linkedList.stream().anyMatch(i -> i % 2 == 0));
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void measureListN(Blackhole blackhole) {
        blackhole.consume(listN.stream().anyMatch(i -> i % 2 == 0));
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void measureHashSet(Blackhole blackhole) {
        blackhole.consume(hashSet.stream().anyMatch(i -> i % 2 == 0));
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void measureLinkedHashSet(Blackhole blackhole) {
        blackhole.consume(linkedHashSet.stream().anyMatch(i -> i % 2 == 0));
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void measureSetN(Blackhole blackhole) {
        blackhole.consume(setN.stream().anyMatch(i -> i % 2 == 0));
    }
}
```

Environment

- JDK: openjdk version "15.0.2" 2021-01-19
- OS: Window 10
- CPU: i7-8750H
- Memory: 16G Ram